# background Content of div occurs in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, navbar

I am using creative bootsrap theme where the background image occurs in navbar and it changes only when i scroll.
i dont want the navbar to change when scrolled it should be default with white background which occurs when i scroll.
here is the link for the template
https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/[This is by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNNtC.jpg)

[I want my navbar to be like this throughout and not only when i scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvOvF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**This will fix your problem**

The white `background-color` is adding from `js` .

With one step you can get this header by adding `navbar-shrink` this class to here `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">` .

**OR**

**You can change your css like this**.

**`background-color and border-color`**

```
#mainNav {
    border-color: transparent; /* need to change */
    background-color: transparent; /* need to change */
}

#mainNav {
    border-color: 1px solid #22262a;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**`Logo Color(nav-brand)`**

```
#mainNav .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7); /* need to change */
}
#mainNav .navbar-brand {
    color: #f05f40;
}
```

**`Link Color(a)`**

```
#mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a.nav-link, #mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a.nav-link:focus {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7); /* need to change */
}
#mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a.nav-link, #mainNav .navbar-nav>li.nav-item>a.nav-link:focus {
    color: #212529;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it position fixed instead of relative by adding below code:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This class applies the white and orange when you scroll down:

`#mainNav.navbar-shrink`

Just apply whatever navbar-shrink applies to your #mainNav,

```
// white background
#mainNav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(33,37,41,.1);
    background-color: #fff;
}
// orange branding title
#mainNav .navbar-brand {
    color: #f05f40;
}
// black navigation links
#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link {
  color: #212529; 
}
```

That should be enough, but if you want to clean up further remove the Javascript part that actually adds that navbar-shrink part, 
the function should contain something like:

`$("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");`

You won't need it

Try not to use !important in your css selectors, your code will get messy

Comment: i have done this but now the navbar is white but the text are also white

Comment: HI, @BharatRathore, have you added this?
#mainNav .navbar-brand {
    color: #f05f40;
}
Make sure to remove the JS that adds the shrink class, you may also want to remove the .navbar-shrink from the CSS since you wont need it

Comment: Also, your nav items on the right side of the nav will need to be black right?
#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link, 
#mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link:focus {
    color: #212529;
}